# Sending a message to a service bus queue via .NET Core Logger?

Tags: asynchronous, logging, .net-core, azure-servicebus-queues

I have created a custom logger which sends messages to a service bus queue. My problem is that the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger has no async Log method, so am having to call an async method synchronously which can cause issues.

```
    _queueClient.SendAsync(message).Wait();
```

So my questions is, what is the safest way for me to accomplish this without it causing thread starvation?

Comment: Those messages you send: Are those log messages or part of the normal program flow e.g. notifying other components that an entity was deleted?

Comment: It's using ILogger so is for information, errors, warnings etc.

Answer (score 1):

Net Core Logging is designed specifically to not use async methods. They believe that logging should be quick enough that it doesnt need it.

> "Logging should be so fast that it isn't worth the performance cost of
>   asynchronous code."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

The recommendation is that if you need to log stuff like this, you use a "Batched Logger" instead.

> "Instead, synchronously add log messages to an in-memory queue and have
>   a background worker pull the messages out of the queue to do the
>   asynchronous work of pushing data to SQL Server."

So, basically, you should move your queue calls into a background worker (HostedService) and get it to do the async calls in the background worker instead. Your normal "logger" method should call something that sticks the messages into a MemoryCache queue or something similar and then your background worker will fetch the out of there in the background. I'm sure (off the top of my head) the Azure Logger has a simple example of this sort of thing

Comment: Thanks for the response. WHat they describe in that scenario is not what I am doing i.e. call to SQL, I'm simply putting the message on a queue to be processed by a worker, which is the correct thing to do in this type of scenario. However, because SB queueclient is only async and logger is sync means that I'm now in a situation where there could be deadlocks in my code.

Comment: I guess the decision was taken by MS to implement it the way they did because they didnt anticipate (or care too much) about the scenarios outside of their scope.. Implementing the async part of it in your background service and just using the standard sync methods would allow you to seperate the concerns while still keeping with the current standard way of working.